# Write individual array elements to unique files

Tags: python

I have two arrays, `infile` and `outfile`:

```
infile = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana']
outfile = ['Applefile', 'Orangefile', 'Bananafile']
```

I search `readin.txt` for each element of the `infile` array, and for any line containing said element, I do a couple of things. This is what `readin.txt` looks like:

```
Apple = 13
Celery = 2
Orange = 5
Banana = 
Grape = 4
```

The `outfile` array contains the names of files I would like to create; each corresponding to an element in `infile`. The first element in `infile` corresponds to the first element (file name) in `outfile`, and so on.

The problem I'm having is with this bit of code:

```
for line in open("readin.txt", "r"):
    for i in infile:
        if i in line:
            sp = line.split('=')
            sp1 = str(sp[1])
            def parseline(l):
                return sp1.strip() if len(sp) > 1 and sp[1].strip() != '' else None
                for s in outfile:          
                    out = parseline(line)
                    outw = open(s, "w")
                    outw.write(str(out))
                    outw.close()
```

In the first part of the code, I want to search `readin.txt` for any one of the words from `infile` (i.e. `Apple`, `Orange`, and `Banana`). I then want the code to select out the entire line in which that word occurs. I know that any such line in `readin.txt` will contain an equal sign, so I then want the code to split the line around the equal sign, and produce only that which follows the equal sign.

While the last part of the code indeed creates separate files for each element in `outfile`, the actual output always corresponds to the last element of `infile`. It's as though each subsequent step in the loop overwrites the previous steps. I feel like I need to be looking at the `i`-th elements of `line`, but I'm not sure how to do that in Python. Any help would be great.

**Editing for clarity and hopes of having the question re-opened:**

In fact, the following code seems to do exactly what I want:

```
for line in open("parameters.txt", "r"):
    for i in infile:
        if i in line:
            sp = line.split('=')
            sp1 = str(sp[1]).strip() if len(sp) > 1 and sp[1].strip() != '' else None      
            print sp1
```

On the command line, I get:

```
13
5
None
```

So this tells me that the first portion of the code is doing essentially what I want it to (although perhaps not in the most efficient way, so any other suggestions would be appreciated).

At this point, I'd like all of the information that was printed out to be written to individual files based on the outfile array. ie. `13` should be entered into a file called `Applefile`, `None` should be written into a file called `Bananafile`, etc. This is the point at which I'm having trouble. I know that 'outfile' should be indexed similarly, so that the first element of outfile corresponds to the first element of infile, but my attempts so far have not worked.

This is my most recent attempt:

```
for line in open("parameters.txt", "r"):
    for i in infile:
        if i in line:
            def parseline(l): 
                sp = l.split('=')
                sp1 = str(sp[1]).strip() if len(sp) > 1 and sp[1].strip() != '' else None      
                if sp1:
                    out = parseline(line)
                    outw = open(outfile[i], "w")
                    outw.write(line)
                    outw.close()
```

where defining `parseline` any sooner in the code negates the whole beginning part of the code for some reason.

I'm not looking for just the answer. I would like to understand what is going on and be able to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Why are you using `i` in both loops?! And why are you using the whole `line`, not `i`, inside the loop? What on earth did you expect would happen?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Obviously because I don't know what I'm doing -- hence my asking for help. I've been using python for exactly 1 week now. Some constructive criticism might be more helpful than just blatantly ridiculing me.

I'm using the whole line because I want to extract specific information on that line, and not just what is defined in the array.

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for SO. I suggest you review the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/).

Comment: How is this not an appropriate question? Because I'm not at your level of knowledge? If I delete all subsequent lines, beginning with def parseline, and just insert "print line," the output I get is exactly what I expect. Something thereafter is going wrong, and I don't understand what, evidently because I am not as experienced. But I don't think this is a "basic tutorial" problem. Your unwillingness to help is quite astounding.

Comment: No; because you haven't actually provided enough information to help without just rewriting it for you. Recursive call notwithstanding, you don't show where `parseline` is called (side note: you would be much better off defining it once with explicit arguments than relying on scope) and with what argument. You haven't provided example inputs and expected and actual outputs. You didn't mention until pressed what you had done to try to figure it out and the result of doing so. And not knowing how to access elements by index is certainly a '"basic tutorial" problem'.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've edited the question for clarity. I apologize for the initially ill-conceived post.

Comment: Where are you actually *calling* `parseline`? Is that the actual indentation you're using?

Answer (score 0):

> the actual output within every single file created corresponds to the last element of infile

because for every element of infile, you are looping over every element of outfile and writing the latest line, so it makes sense that you end up with all files containing the last line. Since your infile/outfile lines correspond you can use the i index from the main infile loop to grab the label you want from outfile.. something like:

```
for line in open("readin.txt", "r"):
    for i in infile:
        if i in line:
            sp = line.split('=')
            sp1 = str(sp[1]).strip() if len(sp) > 1 and sp[1].strip() != '' else None
            if sp1:
                out = parseline(line)
                outw = open(outfile[i], "w")
                outw.write(str(out))
                outw.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately this doesn't quite do the trick. Since parseline is not defined in your code, I tried defining it in various places, but that doesn't seem to work either. When I run essentially what you have there, I don't get any errors, but none of the files are created.

Answer (score 0):

I would break this down into two steps:

```
def parse_params(filename):
    """Convert the parameter file into a map from filename to value."""
    out = {}
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            word, num = map(str.strip, line.split("="))
            out[word] = num
    return out # e.g. {'Celery': '2', 'Apple': '13', 'Orange': '5'}

def process(in_, out, paramfile):
    """Write the values defined in param to the out files based on in_.""" 
    value_map = parse_params(paramfile)
    for word, filename in zip(infile, outfile):
        if word in value_map:
            with open(filename, 'w') as f: # or '"{0}.txt".format(filename)'
                f.write(value_map[word])
        else:
            print "No value found for '{0}'.".format(word)

process(infile, outfile, "parameters.txt")
```

---

Your current code really doesn't make much sense:

```
for line in open("parameters.txt", "r"): # iterate over lines in file
    for i in infile: # iterate over words in infile list
        if i in line: # iterate over characters in the file line (why?)
            def parseline(l): # define a function
                sp = l.split('=')
                sp1 = str(sp[1]).strip() if len(sp) > 1 and sp[1].strip() != '' else None      
                if sp1:
                    out = parseline(line)
                    outw = open(outfile[i], "w")
                    outw.write(line)
                    outw.close()
# but apparently never call it (why?)
```

Using the same loop variable name in two loops is a bad idea, you only ever see the inner value:

```
>>> for x in range(2):
    for x in "ab":
        print x


a
b
a
b
```

If you find that a function "needs" to be defined in a particular place, it suggests that you are relying on scoping to access variables. It is much better to define specific arguments and return values for the parameters you need; it makes development and testing significantly easier.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what each 'filename' is referring to. In your first step as you're defining the function, `def parseparams(filename)`, can you explain to me how you're actually calling parameters.txt without explicitly writing it? 

I'm also not quite sure I understand what exactly these two lines are doing:

`word, num = map(str.strip, line.split("="))`
`out[word] = num`

Comment: @user2068783 do you remember when you claimed this wasn't a basic tutorial issue? See e.g. [`def parse_params(filename):`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions), [`map(str.strip, line.split("="))`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#functional-programming-tools), [`out[word] = num`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)